# Crash when calling optional protocol method

Tags: iphone, ios, protocols

I use a protocol with some optional methods.

```
@protocol PhotoDropDownDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
    - (void)getEditResult:(NSString *)status;
    - (void)getImageForDiagram:(UIImage *)image andImagePath:(NSString *)imagePath;
    - (void)dismissPhotoDropDown;

@end
```

I assign this for a class

```
photoDropDownViewController.photoDropDownDelegate = self;
```

I use only one method

```
- (void)getImageForDiagram:(UIImage *)image andImagePath:(NSString *)imagePath
{
    // Make a Image on center of screen
    PhotoLayer *photoLayer = [PhotoLayer nodeWithLengthOfShape:300 andHeight:200 andPathToImage:imagePath];
    photoLayer.position = ccp(400, 500);
    photoLayer.nameObject = [self makeNewName_ForShape];    
    photoLayer.isSelected_BottomRightElip = YES;
    photoLayer.isSelected = YES;


    [photoLayer doWhenSelected_Elip_BottomRight];
    [photoLayer show_Elip];

    [list_Shapes addObject:photoLayer];

    [self addChild:photoLayer];
    photoLayer = nil;

    // Set Button Delete
    selected_GerneralShapeLayer = (GerneralShapeLayer *) [list_Shapes lastObject];
    [self updateStatusForButtonDelete];
}
```

Then the compiler show error:

> `[AddDiagramLayer dismissPhotoDropDown]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb2a8320'`

when I implement the others methods the error is disappear

```
-(void)getEditResult:(NSString *)status {

}

-(void)dismissPhotoDropDown {

}
```

As I've known, if a method in @option we can use it or not.
I don't understand what happened here. Can anyone explain to me

Comment: Well, even if you make it optional, if you try to call it there will be a problem right?

Comment: no, i just use one of them. And do not implement the others, it will make error

Comment: Yes but obviously you tried to call it `[AddDiagramLayer dismissPhotoDropDown]`. You can't if you don't implement.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

All the `@optional` directive does is suppresses compiler warnings if the optional methods are not implemented. However, if you call a method that the class does not implement, the app will still crash, as the selector (method) you tried to call is not recognised by the class, since it's not implemented.

You can work around this by checking whether the delegate implements a method before calling it:

```
// Check that the object that is set as the delegate implements the method you are about to call
if ([self.photoDropDownDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(dismissPhotoDropDown)]) {
    // The object does implement the method, so you can safely call it.
    [self.photoDropDownDelegate dismissPhotoDropDown];
}
```

This way, if the delegate object implements an optional method, it will be called. Otherwise, it won't, and your program will continue running as normal.

Note that you should still use the `@optional` directive to denote methods that are optional to implement, in order to avoid compiler warnings when you don't implement them. This is particularly important for open source software or libraries that will be distributed to clients, as this directive tells the developers that haven't read your implementation, but can only see the header, that they don't need to implement these methods, and everything will still be fine.